# Show webform textfield conditionally based on "radio other"

Tags: webforms

I have a webform "radio other", with options like "1, 2, 3, more".
For "more", "radio other" is configured to add a textfield for custom values.

Now the problem is that I want to hide the custom text-field until "other" is selected, and if it's possible to do so with the existing conditional logic I can't work it out.

I've tried to work out a way to add conditional logic to the "radio other" element, but it appears I can only do so to the whole element, and not just the other part.
I've also tried adding another text-field, and have it's visibility be conditioned to the "more" choice, but I can't seem to chose that in the webform conditions dialog, as it only displays the 1,2,3 options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the condition for the text field: Edit the webform text field and under "Condition" (I am not sure about the label in English) you choose for the status "visible" and under "Element" you choose your radio button element and as "Trigger/value" you choose "value is" (in the select box) and in the field you then choose your value "other".

With this set your text field appears when you choose "other" from the radio buttons.